# Get results from model, order by sum of columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In Laravel 5.3 I have a User model. I want to have the 10 users with the highest ranking on my server. The ranking is based on a sum of the columns `Rank_a`, `Rank_b` and `Rank_c`. How can I do that?

This is the code I have so far:

```
$users = User::take(10)
        ->select(DB::raw('sum(Rank_a+Rank_b+Rank_c) AS total_points'))
        ->orderBy('total_points')
        ->get();
return response()->json($users);
```

Comment: Does this query not returning expected result?

Comment: Nope, returning empty response: `[[]]`

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the columns you want to get in `select()`. Also, since you want to get the users with the highest rankings, you should sort them in descending order.

Assuming that you need to get the columns `id` and `username`:

```
$users = User::select(
    DB::raw('id, username, Rank_a + Rank_b + Rank_c AS total_points')
)->orderBy('total_points', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```

If you want to get all columns:

```
$users = User::select(
    DB::raw('users.*, Rank_a + Rank_b + Rank_c AS total_points')
)->orderBy('total_points', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```

And if you just want to get an array of one column, say, `id`:

```
$users = User::select(
    DB::raw('id, Rank_a + Rank_b + Rank_c AS total_points')
)->orderBy('total_points', 'desc')->take(10)->pluck('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query:

```
$users = User::take(10)
            ->select('users.*', DB::raw('(Rank_a+Rank_b+Rank_c) AS total_points'))
            ->orderBy('total_points', 'desc')
            ->get();
```